# How to get Sentinel logged user to front-end

Tags: php, laravel, sentinel

I want to get the sentinel logged user to front-end. In my front-end blade PHP I used `Sentinel::check()` method. But it `return false`. When I check the same condition in the controller class it `return true`. So I want to find out how to get the logged user to front-end.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Sentinel, but you can make a variable available to all of your views. In your **AppServiceProvider@boot** add `view()->share( 'isUserLogged', Sentinel::check() );` and it will be available on all your views like this `$isUserLogged`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the logged user to all the front-end pages by adding following line of code to boot method in AppServiceProvider.php class.

```
view()->share( 'loggedUser', Sentinel::getUser() );
```

After that you can access the Sentinel user from the loggedUser variable in all the front-end classes. Form it you can access all the `Sentinel::getUser()` related methods from the front-end.